# Passing and retaining NSString to another view when popping current view

Tags: ios

I have a method that will dismiss the current view in the navigation controller and replace it with another view.  The code looks like this

```
-(void)didTransferRequest:(NSString *)_transferComments {

    AddRequestViewController *ar = [[AddRequestViewController alloc]
             initAsTransferForRequestID:requestID 
             withClosingComments: _transferComments]];

    UINavigationController *currentNav = self.navigationController;

    [[self retain] autorelease];

    [currentNav popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [currentNav pushViewController:ar animated:NO];

    [ar release];

}

[AddRequestViewController.m]

-(AddRequestViewController *)initAsTransferForRequestID:(int)requestID 
                            withClosingComments:(NSString *)closingComments{
    self = [self initWithStyle:  UITableViewStyleGrouped];

    if (self) {
       _requestID = requestID;
       _closingComments = closingComments;
    }

    return self;
}
```

The problem is that once the new view is pushed onto the nav stack, it crashes when the view attempts to access the contents passed in by _transferComments.  The pointer is pointing to something else which would make sense since the view gets popped.

I was successful in using withTransferComments: [_transferComments copy] but the Analyzer identified a memory leak with this.

Is using copy safe and should I ignore the leak message or is there a better way to send the string over?

Answer (score 0):

Your `AddRequestViewController` isn't taking ownership of `_transferComments`.

You need to read [Cocoa Core Competencies - Memory Management](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MemoryManagement.html) and [Basic Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1).

In the code snippet you posted (without the copy), I deduce that `AddRequestViewController` doesn't send `retain` to `_transferComments`.  If it wants to make sure `_transferComments` stays around, it needs to send it the `retain` message to take ownership of the string.  When `AddRequestViewController` is done with the string, it needs to send it `release` to relinquish ownership.  You would probably do this in `-[AddRequestViewController dealloc]`.

Basically, your `initAsTransferForRequestID:withClosingComments:` method should look something like this:

```
- (id)initAsTransferForRequestID:(int)requestId withClosingComments:(NSString *)transferComments {
    if (!(self = [super init]))
        return nil;

    _requestId = requestId;
    _transferComments = [transferComments retain];

    return self;
}
```

(Note that I'm using the common convention of naming instance variables with a leading underscore.)  Your dealloc method should look like this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [_transferComments release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

When you changed your code to copy `_transferRequest`, you did create a memory leak.  The `copy` message creates an "owning" reference to the copy, and something needs to take responsibility for relinquishing that ownership.  You didn't change either of your objects to do that.

Comment: Ah, excellent.  Thanks for the detailed response, Rob.  I'll check out those articles as well.